# Issues with valid multipart/mixed and Google Drive

Tags: http, file-upload, google-drive-api

I am attempting to upload a file to Google Drive using the "upload" URL with a type of "multipart". I'm trying to do this without a library and using basic HTTP with a multipart POST. With a body like the following, I am constantly getting the error "Invalid multipart request with 0 mime parts."

1. The HTTP message looks valid to me. Is there something obvious that I'm missing or doing wrong?
2. Is there a protocol tester that can verify if my POST body is valid or not?

`POST /upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart HTTP/1.1
Authentiction: Bearer {valid auth_token}
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="--314159265358979323846"
host: localhost:3004
content-length: 254
Connection: keep-alive`

--314159265358979323846
Content-Type: application/json

{"title":"Now","mimeType":"text/plain"}
--314159265358979323846
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Mon Jun 17 2013 20:59:02 GMT-0400 (EDT)
--314159265358979323846--

(The segments look like they have double newlines. I think this is an artifact of the pasting, they are CRLF pairs in the code and appear as a newline when testing, but I guess this could theoretically be the problem, but I'd like proof.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`boundary` attribute on the `Content-Type` header should not include double dashes. Use the following as your `Content-Type`:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="314159265358979323846"
```